# PHP: preg_match and group repetition

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all, preg-split

How I can get all matched objects in a group using `preg_match` (or `preg_match_all`, maybe)?

For instance, I have `^(?:,?\s*(?<key>[a-z]))+$`, if I apply to `a, b, c`, I get this:

```
object array
    0  : string "a, b, c"
    key: string "c"
    1  : string "c"
```

I need basically of get `a`, `b` and `c`. Something like it (don't needly like it):

```
object array
    0  : string "a, b, c"
    key: object array
        0  : string "a"
        1  : string "b"
        2  : string "c"
    ...
```

It's possible? What is the better solution? I need really to split it after match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split it on `,\s*`, eg:

```
$array = preg_split("/,\\s*/", "a, b,   c,d,e");
```

Answer (score 1):

No you can not nest it like that. You can build the array manually however.

```
$str = 'a, b, c';
preg_match_all("/(\w),?/", $str, $m);

// create array
$a = array(
    $str,
    'key' => $m[1]
);

print_r($a);
```

You can use `preg_split` too go grab this elements.

```
$m = preg_split('/\W+/', $str, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```